# E0401:Unable to import 'pyspark in VSCode in Windows 10

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, visual-studio-code

I have installed below on my windows 10 machine to use the Apache Spark.

**Java,
 Python 3.6 and
 Spark (spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7)**

I am trying to write pyspark related code in VSCode. It is showing red underline under the 'from  ' and showing error message

> E0401:Unable to import 'pyspark'

I have also used ctrl+Shift+P and select "Python:Update workspace Pyspark libraries". It is showing notification message

> Make sure you have SPARK_HOME environment variable set to the root path of the local spark installation!

[image]

[image]

[image: SPARK_HOME and JAVA_HOME]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install the [pyspark](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/) Python package using `pip install pyspark`. Actually, this is the only package you'll need for VSCode, unless you also want to run your Spark application on the same machine.