# How to add or append python or PySpark modules to PYTHONPATH in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pyspark, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

Two approaches to setup Pyspark in an IDE are :

1. Using Pip i.e pip install pyspark , As mentioned in the following link ( [E0401:Unable to import 'pyspark in VSCode in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185767/e0401unable-to-import-pyspark-in-vscode-in-windows-10))
2. By appending PySpark modules in "PYTHONPATH" path, as mentioned in following articles.

   - [PySpark in Eclipse: using PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326749/pyspark-in-eclipse-using-pydev)
   - https://blog.puneethabm.com/pyspark-dev-set-up-eclipse-windows/

The second approach is backward compatible and can be setup in most IDEs, **So wanted to know how can one setup up "PYTHONPATH" in visual studio code** .

I believe something needs to be done either in **settings.json , launch.json or may be even in .env file**. But I could not find something concrete.

Also, I went through the visual studio code at link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable . However was still not able to figure out

**How to "append" python or PySpark modules to PYTHONPATH**

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean with **PYTHONPATH** but if you have installed Python correctly (with environment variables) and installed pyspark correct (`pip install pyspark` or `pip3 install pyspark`). You should simply call: `python file.py` or `python3 file.py`.

Comment: @Spirit , Using pip install pyspark is one way to do it, however adding pyspark.zip and py4j-0.10.4-src.zip to "PYTHONPATH" is more flexible as that same build can be used for coding in other languages and even in case of update its across all the setups.

Comment: I have no experience with this option. But maybe try and make a own Environment Variable for the file.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code) for setting environment variables for VSCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it via a `.env` file then it should be:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/zip
```